# Why is this procedure wrong? (Frullani's Integral)

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

It is known that for $a,b>0$,
   $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x}\ dx=\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
However, I was asked to show why the following procedure is incorrect:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x}\ dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{x}\ dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-bx}}{x}\ dx \stackrel{\text{c.o.v.}}{=}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{u}}{u}\ dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{u}}{u}\ dx=0 $$
I can't seem to find a mistake with the procedure, maybe I am missing something? I presume that you cannot seperate the integral, but the function is defined everywhere.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2}{n^2}$$ is convergent to $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$, but we cannot state $$\frac{\pi^2}{3} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n+1}{n^2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n-1}{n^2}$$ since both the series in the RHS are divergent. Same issue above.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That is true! Thank you!

Comment: $c.o.v.{}{}{}$ ???

Comment: @reuns change of variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure is incorrect because $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{x}dx$$ does not converge (the integral of $1/x$ diverges at the origin). The equation $$\int (f(x)+g(x)) dx = \int f(x) dx +\int g(x) dx$$ is only valid if both integrals converge.

Comment: I missed that! Thank you!

Comment: @DMH16 no problem. This problem at the origin suggests a way to modify what you have above to prove the original integral: note that you want to compute $$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}dx. $$